# Book about training for and surviving on a deadly planet

Tags: story-identification, novel, soft-sci-fi

Looking for a 1960s book about people who think they are first training for and then fortifying on a planet where all the vegetation and other life is deadly and actively trying to kill intruders. Plants actively try to eat through the walls of their fortress, for example. The weapons people use are connected to their reflexes somehow.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trying to remember a book about a human male travelling to alien planet](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/160589/trying-to-remember-a-book-about-a-human-male-travelling-to-alien-planet)

Comment: OP comment to answer below looks like fairly positive confirmation.

Comment: I've voted to leave this open, I'm not a big fan of "fairly positive" either we wait until there's strict confirmation or until it sounds right. Our policies say do the former so we should do the former.

Answer (score 27):

Harry Harrison’s [*Deathworld*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deathworld) trilogy.

It features deadly plants and "forearm mounted automatic holsters".

> The planet was called Pyrrus...a strange place where all the beasts, plants and natural elements were designed for one specific purpose: to destroy man.
>   The settlers there were supermen...twice as strong as ordinary men and with milli-second reflexes. They had to be. For their business was murder...
>   It was up to Jason dinAlt, interplanetary gambler, to discover why Pyrrus had become so hostile during man's brief habitation...
>
> <sub>[Goodreads, Deathworld 1](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2037559.Deathworld_1)</sub>

Comment: Pretty sure this is it... got it ordered and I will read to make sure. Thanks

Comment: @CarlM If this is indeed the correct answer be sure to click the checkmark next to the voting buttons on this answer.