# Hell-world created by psionic waves from a plant in a cave

Tags: story-identification, books

I read this book a long time ago.

Some people arrived on a planet that everyone knows is a hellworld. The humans live in a fortress that is constantly besieged by wild animals; keeping the humans safe is a significant effort. But there are also some humans who live outside the fortress in tune with nature; nobody really knows how they manage it.

Someone is doing experiments with psionic waves and realizes they are causing the wildlife to go crazy. The main characters go on an expedition in a flying machine with a directional psi-wave detector, and they narrow down the source of the psi-waves to a cave. They enter the cave and find the waves are coming from some very angry plants.

Comment: In roughly which year did you read this and when do you think it might've been published? Also, do you recall anything about the cover?

Comment: The question was closed as a duplicate because you confirmed that the book you were looking for is _Deathworld_ by Harry Harrison, which is the same book an [earlier story-ID question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/160589/trying-to-remember-a-book-about-a-human-male-travelling-to-alien-planet) was looking for. Don't take it as any sort of criticism of your question. It's the standard practice on this site to close a story-ID question if it turns out that it was asking about a work already asked about in another story-ID question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is Harry Harrison's [*Deathworld*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?2127) (1960); the plants in the cave turn out not to actually be the *source* of the psionic signal, merely repeaters that strengthen it.  There is quite an extensive [synopsis available on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deathworld#Synopsis).

> **Everything on the planet is deadly to humans. The large animals are strong enough to destroy small vehicles, while the small ones have neurotoxic venom. Even the plants are deadly**. All microorganisms consume insufficiently protected tissue as quickly as acids. On top of all this, life evolves so quickly that even Kerk and his Pyrran crew have to be retrained upon their return in order to survive.
>
> Because of this harsh environment, **the settlers are engaged in a ceaseless struggle to survive**, which – despite generations of acclimation and a training regime harsher than that of ancient Spartans – they are losing. The money Jason won is used to buy desperately needed weapons.
>
> While acclimating to the harsh planet, Jason turns his attentions toward solving the planet's mysteries and saving the faltering colony. The few surviving historical records show Jason that the settlers' numbers have dwindled since the planet was first colonized, and they are now restricted to a single settlement. Extrapolating backward, it is clear to Jason that the flora and fauna were once far less hostile to humans. **Jason also learns of greatly despised "grubbers", humans living outside the city**, with whom the Pyrrans grudgingly trade hardware for increasingly necessary food.
>
> After several weeks, Jason leaves the city in search of **the grubbers, who live in harmony with the harsh environment. They practice what many would consider suicidal forms of animal husbandry, with the assistance of their telepathic "talkers"**. Jason is able to earn their trust by demonstrating his own abilities. The outsiders' knowledge of the initial colonization effort is even more intriguing than that of the city dwellers. Not long after their arrival, animals suddenly began attacking the city, and have not stopped since. However, a number of colonists lived outside the city. Though they still found the planet incredibly harsh, they never suffered such attacks. The grubbers are their descendants. The two factions despise each other. The grubbers hate the city Pyrrans, or "junkmen", for cutting them off from space and refusing to trade food or ore for scientific knowledge or advanced technology, particularly medicine. The junkmen hate the grubbers for thriving while they are dying.
>
> While studying the grubber community, he notices an anomaly—though the life-forms throughout the area are dangerous, they are nowhere near as lethal as the ones around the city. Some grubbers theorize that the initial schism was a disagreement over the city's location, in which the ancestors of the grubbers abandoned the dangerous ground in favor of their current homes. Jason has the grubbers guide him back to the city, so he can see it from the outside. There his psionic senses confirm his hypothesis. **Every species of native flora and fauna is psionic, and all life around the city is telepathically "shouting" the same thing: "KILL THE ENEMY!"** Pyrrus' biosphere is intentionally attacking the city.
>
> Jason shares this information with the grubbers and wins their total support. They ask Jason to go back to civilization and return with a ship. In return they will reward him handsomely. Jason agrees, but only to get back to the city. He knows that though the grubbers would keep their word, the first thing they would get from civilization would be weapons with which to make war on the city. He has a better idea, and shares it with Kerk along with the truth about the attacks.
>
> **Jason builds a device that can track the intelligence giving commands to the native flora and fauna to attack the city**, and puts it in the city's spaceship to search. **They detect that the psychic commands emanate from a cave on an island far from the city**. Jason prepares to go down and "talk" to what may be an alien intelligence, but the junkmen decide instead to attack and kill the intelligence. The resulting battle ends with hundreds dead, along with the intelligence after the entire island is destroyed in a nuclear blast. However, the attacks on the city grow even worse than before. Kerk blames Jason for the loss of the attack team (although the order to attack was given by him) and the futility of the plan and prepares to kill him. Jason is barely able to flee in an escape pod, but it is shot down by Kerk.